# Topology: Suppose $A\subset B\subset C$ and $\overline{C}=A^{\circ}$. Show $B$ is open and closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $A\subset B\subset C$ and $\overline{C}=A^{\circ}$. Show $B$ is open and closed.

I'm relatively new to topology and the following is what I "THINK" I've proven but not exactly sure. I would really appreciate if someone corrected me if I'm wrong or if there is more direct way to do this as I don't feel too confident in my proof.

For reference these are the definitions I was given and therefore been using for the proof.

$x\in\overline{A}\iff\forall(G\in\tau, x\in G),(G\cap A\neq\emptyset=\exists y\in G\cap A)$.

$x\in A^\circ\iff\exists G\in\tau,x\in G\subset A$.

$x\in A^a\iff\forall(G\in\tau,x\in G),\exists y\neq x\in G\cap A$.

$\bf{Proof:}$ Assume $A\subset B\subset C$ and $\overline{C}=A^\circ$.

$\overline{C}=A^\circ\Rightarrow \overline{C}\subset A^\circ$ and $A^\circ\subset\overline{C}$.

Consider $x\in A^\circ$, then $\exists G\in\tau$ such that $x\in G\subset A$.

$x\in A\Rightarrow x\in\overline{C}\Rightarrow\exists y\neq x\in G\cap C\Rightarrow y\in G$ and $y\in A$.

Since $G\subset A\Rightarrow G\subset A\subset B\subset C$ and $y\in G$ then $y\in G\subset A\subset B\subset C$ in particular $y\in B$.

Because $y\in G$ and $y\in B\Rightarrow \exists y\neq x\in G\cap B$ then $x\in B^a$.

Then $x\in G\subset A\Rightarrow x\in A\subset B\subset C$ in particular $x\in B$ then $B^a\subset B\Rightarrow B$ is closed.

I'm not sure if I'm using the definitions correctly but so far this is what I think I've proven. If this is actually correct, I have no clue how to prove that $B$ is open now. I would appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\bar{C} =A^{\circ} \subset A \subset B \subset C \subset \bar{C} $ shows that all inclusions are actually equalities. Then $B=\bar{C}=A^{\circ}$ which is indeed closed and open.

Comment: You see, Topology is very new to me and it's the little things like that I'm still trying to grasp. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

$A^° \subset A$, $A^°$ is open.

$C \subset \overline{C}$, $\overline{C}$ is closed.

Given that $A^° = \overline {C} $,

$A^° \subset A \subset B \subset C \subset \overline{C}$

implies

$A^°= A= B = C = \overline {C}.$

Hence all the above sets are open and closed.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was greatly appreciated.

Comment: Luis, it is a pleasure, all the more, since I am digging a bit into Topology.One of the masters in this field (Stackexchange) is User Carlos.:))

Comment: I'm sure there are tons of Carlos on MSE. Do you happen to know his full user ID. His help might come in handy, not that everyone else's hasn't been useful already.

Comment: Luis. Name: José Carlos Santos. Click on users and his name comes up, second.

Comment: Perfect, thanks again!